# compressed / minified prototype file

Tags: prototypejs

I need a compressed minified prototype file.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, there's no official or hosted minified build of Prototype. You can run it through [`jsmin`](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) easily enough, but then you have to host it yourself. Or as [Tomasz pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699783/compressed-minified-prototype-file/3699791#3699791), you can use the unminified (but gzipped) version from [Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#prototype).

Answer (score 2):

Google does not hurt: http://prototypejs.org/2008/05/27/prototype-hosted-on-google-s-servers 
(corrected link)

Comment: Right, but it's not minified.

Comment: is it really worth downvoting? tha fact, that Google has it in its CDN is more valuable than minifying.

Comment: i think a downvote is a bit harsh but maybe you should have explained your reasoning for a non-minified version when the OP stated he wanted one

Comment: If you have it minified, user downloads fewer data. If you have it in broadly accessible CDN, user probably downloads nothing. Any questions?

Comment: I'm not seeing any downvotes (now), presumably whoever it was reconsidered. Would **definitely** have been harsh to downvote this.

Comment: now it has positive value, but was -1 at the time ;] thanks, whoever voted up ;]

Comment: @Tomasz: If you click the number, you can see the actual number of up- and down-votes. In this case, it's +1 and -0, so whoever voted down realised their mistake.

Comment: AFAIK these numbers are visible 1k+ rep, so I need 10 more to see this ;]

Comment: The posted link is broken - this one works: http://prototypejs.org/2008/05/27/prototype-hosted-on-google-s-servers/

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I ran prototype.js (v. 1.6) through UglifyJS using http://jscompress.com/, and started getting a bunch of javascript errors. So Google is clearly the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and minimized this file, it went from 130mb to 67 mb. Although I did very minimal testing, everything works on my end with no firebug errors. Please Let me know how it works on your scripts.

Heres the link!
You have to upload the entire file on the right hand side.

http://shrinksafe.dojotoolkit.org/